# Dreaded ???? instead of characters when displaying chinese text. Simplified Chinese Character issue

Tags: php, windows, character-encoding, drupal-6

I am trying to produce a multilingual using Drupal 6. My site is hosted on a Windows IIS 7.5 Server.

I have gotten my .po files uploaded and everything works great. Im now at the stage where I am going through the site piece by piece to try and weed out anything that escaped my notice when I first translated teh site.

The problem I am having is in trying to display dates in locale formats.

Here is the php code I use to display a local date:

```
$format = "%A, %b %#d, %Y : %H:%M%p"

if($language->language == 'zh-hans')
{
    $loc=setlocale(LC_TIME, 'chs');
}else{
    $loc=setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de');
}
$mytime = strftime($format, $time);
$mytime = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($mytime), 'utf-8', $mytime);

echo $mytime;
```

The above code should display the date in the local format of the current language (chinese of german)

The german displays as expected:

> Freitag, Jun 21, 2013 : 16:48

but the chinese output looks like this:

> ???, ?? 21, 2013 : 16:48??

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: where does it look like this? On the console? on a webpage? in the database?

Comment: My guess would be on a web-page and the standard fix of including `header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8');` at the top of the document will probably solve it ... probably ;)

Comment: The results given above are displayed on the website. I have added an echo statement to make that a little clearer. The charset is set to utf-8. I should add that the rest of the page displays perfectly in Chinese text, it is only the date returned by strftime that is displayed as question marks

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @Cypher an interesting read, but not relevant to the question I asked. The problem was not a lack of understanding about the history of Unicode or the importance of Content-Type headers.

Comment: It's relevant in that this question is related to character encoding issues, which is what the article discusses. Granted, it's not a canonical answer for your question (which is why I did not post it as an answer), I still felt it provides enough useful information that it warranted a comment for future visitors to reference.

Comment: @Cypher Perhaps you should have added a note to flag your intention, as it was quite a long read for something that ultimately was not relevant (despite your above comment) to the question being asked!

Comment: This question pertains to character encoding issues. The article is intended for programmers who still haven't figured out character encoding. Relevant to you, and all future visitors. I don't need to "flag my intentions" to link relevant articles. The intent is absolutely clear based on the title of the article, and now made even more clear by the unnecessary ramblings in this questions comments.

Comment: Your comment was related, yes. But relevant? Hardly. Its like you read the title of the question and saw an opportunity to post a link to your favourite article about your biggest pet peeve. Im pretty sure you didn't take the time to read, or at least to comprehend, the question, which is pretty ironic given the length of the article that you subsequently posted for everyone else to read. The code snippet clearly shows an attempt was made to output characters in UTF-8. compare the redundancy of your comment with the invaluable information contained in the accepted answer. But, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that setting the `LC_TIME` category is not enough by itself. The `strftime` function will attempt to format the time in the appropriate language, but it seems to use the 1252 codepage by default, so it will be incapable of producing the necessary characters for something like Chinese.

I would have expected that setting `LC_TIME` and maybe `LC_CTYPE` would be enough, but the only way I could get it to work was with `LC_ALL`. So your `setlocale` calls should look like this:

```
if($language->language == 'zh-hans')
{
    $loc=setlocale(LC_ALL, 'chs');
}else{
    $loc=setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de');
}
```

The next problem is that `mb_detect_encoding` won't always detect the correct encoding. What works for me on Windows is to use `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 0)` to get back the current code page.

```
$codepage = explode('.',setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 0));
$codepage = 'cp'.$codepage[1];
```

The value returned from the call to `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 0)` is a combination of the language name and the codepage number separated by a dot. We split the two parts with `explode` and then prefix the number with `cp` to get the code page in a form that `iconv` can understand.

We can then simply convert the string to utf-8 like this:

```
$mytime = iconv($codepage, 'utf-8', $mytime);
```

Comment: I have to say, that is as complete and informative an answer as Ive ever received on this site. Your time and effort are very much appreciated!